# How does this integral formula form this closed form?

Tags: integration

$\int xe^{-A/B\times x^2} - xe^{-A/B\times (M-x)^2}e^{-A/B\times x^2} dx$

I run this equation in wolfram alpha.
The closed form of the integral is as follows.

$\frac{B e^{\frac{A (-M^2 - 2 x^2)}{B}} \left(\frac{1}{4} e^{\frac{2 A M x}{B}} - \frac{1}{2} e^{\frac{A (M^2 + x^2)}{B}}\right)}{A}
+ \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{B} {M} e^{-\frac{A M^2}{2 B}} \text{erf}\left(\frac{(\sqrt{A} (B - 2 x)}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{B}}\right)}{4 \sqrt{A}}$

erf(x) is the error function. And A,B and M is just variables.

I don't know how this equation is solved.

Comment: Probably integration by parts + substitution to get ride of the messy constants.

Answer (score 1):

You face two integrals
$$I=\int x e^{-\frac{A }{B}x^2}\,dx$$ which is simple using
 $$\frac{A }{B}x^2=t^2\implies x=\sqrt{\frac{B }{A}}t\implies dx=\sqrt{\frac{B }{A}}dt$$ making $$I=\frac B A\int t\, e^{-t^2} \,dt=-\frac B {2A}e^{-t^2}=-\frac B {2A}e^{-\frac{A }{B}x^2}$$

The second one rewrite
$$J=\int x e^{-\frac A B \left(M^2-2 M x+2 x^2\right)}\,dx$$ Start completing the square
$$M^2-2 M x+2 x^2=2\left(x -\frac M 2\right)^2+\frac {M^2}2$$ and .. just continue with an obvious change of variable